# Powershell move folders content to another folders

Tags: powershell, variables, subdirectory

I started learing powershell two weeks ago. I have the following folders structure

```
C:\not prepared\Not ready
    ABCD_EFGH-whatever\work
    IJK-whatever\work
    LMN-whatever\work
    OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever\work

C:\Already ready
    ABCD_EFGH
    IJK
    LMN
    OPRWXY
```

The script will run from `C:\Already ready`. I want to move each `work` folder from `"Not ready\*\"` to `"Already ready\*"` to get

```
C:\not prepared\Not ready
    ABCD_EFGH-whatever
    IJK-whatever
    LMN-whatever
    OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever

C:\Already ready
    ABCD_EFGH\work
    IJK\work
    LMN\work
    OPRWXY\work
```

I don't want to specify exact folder names, as those may change. Only first 3 characters from `Not ready` and `Already ready` subfolders matches. I guess I should read all subfolders' names from both locations, then put them in a array and compare names one by one. What's more, not all folders may always be present in `C:\not prepared\Not ready`.

Is there are smarter way to do it? Please give me a hint or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Item 'C:\not prepared\Not ready\*\work' | ForEach-Object {

  # Derive the destination dir's name from the parent directory name,
  # by taking the string before "-". To also split by "_", use:
  #    $destDir = ($_.Parent.Name -split '[-_]')[0] 
  # To take just the first 3 characters, use:
  #    $destDir = $_.Parent.Name.Substring(0, 3)
  $destDir = ($_.Parent.Name -split '-')[0]

  # Handle the lone exception to the name mapping.
  if ($_.Parent.Name -like 'OPRSTU_WXYZ-*') { $destDir = 'OPRWXY' }

  # Make sure that the destination dir. exists.
  $null = New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Force -Type Directory $destDir

  # Perform the move.
  $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destDir -WhatIf

  # If desired, remove the parent dir. of the source dir.
  Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.Parent.FullName -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note: The solution above assumes two things:

- Each source `work` folder *uniquely* maps to a destination folder.
- If the destination folder happens to exist already, it is assumed not to already have a `work` subfolder.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works very nice.
I will deal with OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever\work ->OPRWXY\work exception outside of the loop. Once I become more experienced, I am going to try extract first 3 characters from folder name and modify the code

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I wanted to compare only first 3 characters from C:\not prepared\Not ready\<folder here>\work with first 3 characters from C:\Already ready\<folder here> to match correct folder. However copy from OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever to OPRWXY folder without changing folder names. I know it has been badly designed

Comment: I'm thinking: Build a hashtable with destination folders (Already ready). Use the three first letters as key. Then you can lookup the dest folder when you enumerate the source folder - if dest doesn't exist in the hashtable, create a new folder based on the source name.

Comment: @Palansen, the problem here isn't lookup efficiency, it's the irregularity of the destination-name logic. And it sounds like hard-coding the `OPRSTU_WXYZ` exception may be all that is needed: `if ($_.Parent.Name -like 'OPRSTU_WXYZ-*') { $destDir = 'OPRWXY' }`

Comment: @mklement0, I wasn't thinking about speed, but about getting to the destination folder based on the first three characters of the source folder. If the names are random, there can be name collision - but maybe some other logic (that creates source folders) prevents that from happening.

Comment: @Palansen, that's what `New-Item -Type Directory -Force` covers: it creates the destination directory _on demand_. But, yes, there could be collisions - but I don't think that's a concern for the OP.

Comment: Yes, I was worried about array efficiency as well.
So far only one folder has incorrect name, so it is not a big deal. I already wrote that exception. Someone badly designed it.
Actually, I can't create any new folders. However that is not an issue, as any new folders will have appropriate names in both locations. So, we may forget about read and use first 3 characters from folders names rule.

Comment: @mklement0, but you still need to find the destination folder. You cannot just copy it. If there is an existing destinatino folder that starts with the first three letters then you must move to that folder.

Comment: I have what I need now. The only thing that is bothering me is `$_ | Split-Path -Parent | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` used to delete entire $_ parent folder. I can't think about any other way without changing path to parent folder. It works but looks 'dirty'

Comment: @Palansen: The solution derives the destination directory name and either creates that directory as a subdirectory or uses an already extant directory with that name  - thanks to `-Force`. (Again, I'm assuming that there's no need to deal with the hypothetical of multiple source directories mapping to the same destination directory).

Comment: @qcjuzzqq, if you want to remove each `work` directory's parent dir. at the source, you can more simply use `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.Parent.FullName -Recurse -Force`

Comment: @mklement0, are you overlooking that "OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever\work" must be moved to "OPRWXY" - because they both begin with "OPR"?

Comment: Currently there is below 10 folders and maximum will be lik 15 or so. So I just used wildcards for the last folder

Comment: @Palansen, there is no _both_ here. Just the need to move `OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever\work` to `OPRWXY\work`, as an _exceptional_ name mapping. Again: This answer is _not_ trying to provide a solution for potential name-mapping collisions - because that is outside the scope of the question. However, I've updated the answer to clarify the constraints and assumptions.

Comment: @mklement0, you may be right. My idea would catch that exception, though. And I admit, I thought that was part of the general pattern. :)

Comment: @Palansen, in order to handle collisions generally, `Test-Path` commands to check if the target folder already exists would be sufficient - while a hashtable-based solution would also work, it strikes me as overkill in this case.

Comment: @mklement0, it was this requirement: '...x\OPRSTU_WXYZ-whatever\work' must be moved to '...y\OPRWXY\work'. I thought it was a requirement to check all folders in the destination too see if there was one with the same XXX letters as the source.